# Could I use "Ending projects(contests)"?

Tags: grammaticality

I have a menu item and a category that is called "Ending projects". It means that in this section are projects(contests) that will end soon (like in 1-2 days). I have also a block on my page called Ending Projects, to take attention. My question is if I can use this form or not. If not, what other form do you suggest, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

eBay uses a sort categories for its listings labeled "Ending Soonest". The term "Auction" is understood from the context.

You might consider "Ending Soon". It is likely that your audience will understand the implied "Projects".

Answer (score 1):

You may very well use "Ending Projects". But, if it doesn't sound snazzy enough for you, you could try "Ending Soon!". That would really catch my eye to see what I am missing!

Answer (score 0):

You could try, "Projects nearing completion" or "Contests with upcoming deadlines."

In some cases, "Active Projects" or "Active Contests" may work fine.

---

edit: some more ideas.

Aging projects (i.e. the projects closest to dying/termination).

Featured projects

Projects Coming Due

Comment: ;( it is too long. Active projects/contests are all. I need to emphasize the fact that this projects in this category will end soon. Something like Ending soon projects.

Comment: Why can I not use "Ending projects"?

Comment: "Ending Projects" works perfectly if you already know what it means. As a first time user, I would probably interpret it as an info page describing a procedure: "How to end a project" rather than a list of projects ending soon. This wouldn't be a problem for a returning user.